# add custom .properties file in unity android package

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have a .properties file that is required by some android java unity plugin that I am writing. I need to add this file to the unity app's package somehow, so once the unity IDE builds the .apk, the file is located in the root of the apk's assets folder.
Where and how do I place this file in the Unity IDE? I tried putting it under Assets, but I inspected the resulting .apk file and the file did not make it there..

any ideas?
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for including files accessible at runtime:

- Managed assets in [Ressources folders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html) accessible via Resources.Load
- Un-managed assets in the [StreamingAssets folder](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) accessible via the File or WWW APIs

Your .properties file should probably reside in the StreamingAssets folder, if you don't need Unity3D to process it. Unity3D will optimize assets in the Resources folders. For example an image will have to set as GUI or Texture in the IDE. Assets in the StreamingAssets folder are raw and not processed by the Unity3D IDE. So a png is a still a regular png at runtime. StreamingAssets is where we store mp4 mobile videos we don't want Unity3D to re-encode.