# How to write .properties file a file in the root of the .apk build from Unity 3d?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622772/add-custom-properties-file-in-unity-android-package) post and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144475/how-to-have-a-file-in-the-root-of-the-android-apk-generated-by-unity3d) post. It does not help to solve exactly what is asked by their authors.

I am building an apk from Unity 3d. Adding files to Assets/StreamingAssets or Assets/Plugins/Android/assets puts the file to /assets folder of final .apk build. Also, using Resources folder is not relevant for my case, because the lib I use loads .property file from classpath.

I need a file to be placed in the same directory as AndroidManifest.xml.

In my project I use Java native code, when testing my plugin from Eclipse I do get required .properties file in the place I need. But when building from Unity the whole project I cannot make it work.

There is an option to decompile apk, put the file, compile and sign, but it seems to be a waste of time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried build project as Android Google Project? Than you get a project that you can open in e.g Eclipse where you can add whatever you want and build/sign app.

Comment: I did, but in this case the app does not start because of some missing files of VoxelBusters social plugin. In the same time, direct android build from Unity runs fine...